# How to Get Proper Tensor Contraction in Sympy:

Tags: python, arrays, vector, sympy, matrix-multiplication

I've lately been attempting to learn the Tensor module from Sympy; however, I keep running into one specific error:

Here's my code:

```
from sympy.tensor.tensor import TensorIndexType, TensorHead, tensor_indices
import sympy as smp

ExTen = TensorIndexType('ExampleTensor')
m, n = tensor_indices('m n', ExTen)
T = TensorHead('T', [ExTen, ExTen])

ExVec = TensorIndexType('ExampleVector')
V = TensorHead('V', [ExVec])

a, b, c, d = smp.symbols('a b c d')
v1, v2 = smp.symbols('v_1, v_2')

(T(n, -m) * V(m)).replace_with_arrays({V(m): smp.Array([[v1], [v2]]), T(n, -m): smp.Array([[a, b], [c, d]])})
```

Running this code in my Jupyter session raises an error; namely:

`ValueError: shapes for tensor V(m) expected to be [dim_E], replacement array shape is (2, 1)`

Which goes away when I turn my array from a vector of dimension (n, 1) to a covector of dimension (1, n):

```
(T(n, -m) * V(m)).replace_with_arrays({V(m): smp.Array([v1, v2]), T(n, -m): smp.Array([[a, b], [c, d]])})
```

It runs fine then; however, the problem is that this specific contraction is akin to matrix multiplication on a vector, which should return a vector.

How would I pass in a (n, 1) vector and be able to carry out this exact computation without triggering said error?

Comment: coming from `numpy`, `smp.Array([v1, v2])` looks more like (2,) than a (1,2) "vector".  It's 1d, not 2d.  I don't  know much about `sympy` is defining these `tensors`, but `numpy` beginners often are confused about how it doesn't actually define "vectors".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display for your 'matrix product' is:

```
In [9]: (T(n, -m) * V(m))
Out[9]: 
 n    E₀
T   ⋅V  
  E₀
```

`T` is 2d, (n,m); `V` is 1d, just (m). `V(m).rank` is 1.

Admittedly I'm fishing around, trying to find commonalities between the numpy arrays that I'm familiar with, and the sympy class.

```
In [65]: Array([1,2]).shape
Out[65]: (2,)
```

Your working replacement:

```
In [117]: expr = T(n, -m) * V(m)

In [118]: dd
Out[118]: 
⎧ n   ⎡a  b⎤   m          ⎫
⎨T  : ⎢    ⎥, V : [v₁  v₂]⎬
⎩  m  ⎣c  d⎦              ⎭

In [119]: expr.replace_with_arrays(dd)
Out[119]: [a⋅v₁ + b⋅v₂  c⋅v₁ + d⋅v₂]
```

`tensorcontraction` says

> Matrix multiplication may be emulated with a proper combination of
> `tensorcontraction` and `tensorproduct`

Trying that with the `Array` objects:

```
In [123]: vv,tt = list(dd.values())

In [124]: vv       # rank 1
Out[124]: [v₁  v₂]

In [125]: tt       # rank 2
Out[125]: 
⎡a  b⎤
⎢    ⎥
⎣c  d⎦

In [126]: tensorproduct(tt,vv)
Out[126]: 
⎡⎡a⋅v₁  a⋅v₂⎤  ⎡c⋅v₁  c⋅v₂⎤⎤
⎢⎢          ⎥  ⎢          ⎥⎥
⎣⎣b⋅v₁  b⋅v₂⎦  ⎣d⋅v₁  d⋅v₂⎦⎦

In [127]: _.shape
Out[127]: (2, 2, 2)
```

Wrong contraction:

```
In [128]: tensorcontraction(tensorproduct(tt,vv),(0,1))
Out[128]: [a⋅v₁ + d⋅v₁  a⋅v₂ + d⋅v₂]
```

desired:

```
In [129]: tensorcontraction(tensorproduct(tt,vv),(1,2))
Out[129]: [a⋅v₁ + b⋅v₂  c⋅v₁ + d⋅v₂]
```

Starting with your (2,1) array, the product has an added dimension:

```
In [131]: vv2 = smp.Array([[v1], [v2]])

In [132]: vv2.shape
Out[132]: (2, 1)

In [133]: tensorproduct(tt,vv2)
Out[133]: 
⎡⎡a⋅v₁⎤  ⎡b⋅v₁⎤⎤
⎢⎢    ⎥  ⎢    ⎥⎥
⎢⎣a⋅v₂⎦  ⎣b⋅v₂⎦⎥
⎢              ⎥
⎢⎡c⋅v₁⎤  ⎡d⋅v₁⎤⎥
⎢⎢    ⎥  ⎢    ⎥⎥
⎣⎣c⋅v₂⎦  ⎣d⋅v₂⎦⎦

In [134]: _.shape
Out[134]: (2, 2, 2, 1)
```

And for a (2,1) result:

```
In [136]: tensorcontraction(tensorproduct(tt,vv2),(1,2))
Out[136]: 
⎡a⋅v₁ + b⋅v₂⎤
⎢           ⎥
⎣c⋅v₁ + d⋅v₂⎦
```

### explicit covector

Explicitly define the 'vector' as having 2 indices (a column matrix):

```
In [170]: ExVec = TensorIndexType('ExampleVector')
     ...: OneVec = TensorIndexType('One')
     ...: p=tensor_indices('p', OneVec)
     ...: V1 = TensorHead('V', [ExVec,OneVec])

In [171]: V1
Out[171]: V(ExampleVector,One)

In [172]: expr
Out[172]: 
 n    E₀ 
T   ⋅V   
  E₀    p
```

Then with your (2,1) array:

```
In [173]: dd1 ={V1(m,-p): smp.Array([[v1],[v2]]), T(n, -m): smp.Array([[a, b], [c, d]])}

In [174]: dd1
Out[174]: 
⎧ n   ⎡a  b⎤   m   ⎡v₁⎤⎫
⎨T  : ⎢    ⎥, V  : ⎢  ⎥⎬
⎩  m  ⎣c  d⎦    p  ⎣v₂⎦⎭

In [175]: expr.replace_with_arrays(dd1)
Out[175]: 
⎡a⋅v₁ + b⋅v₂⎤
⎢           ⎥
⎣c⋅v₁ + d⋅v₂⎦
```

That's the same dense array as in [136]

In languages like MATLAB everything is 2d (or higher).  So (1,n) and (n,1) 'vectors' are natural.  `tensor` here has more the feel of `numpy`, with `ndarrays`, which can be 0, 1, 2, or more.  There isn't a lower bound of 2d.  So shapes like (n,) are just as natural as (1,n) or n,1).  In fact by 'rules of broadcasting' (n,) behaves a lot like (1,n).  Making a 'column vector' requires an explicit trailing dimension.

There is `smp.vector` module, but it doesn't seem to have any connection to this `tensor` module.

Comment: Thanks :) It seems a bit unnatural to define vectors as having two indices, but it certainly works. I guess you just have to find "hacky" workarounds in order to get things working.